# WooCommerce Subscription plugin emits warning: "class 'WC_CDP' does not have a method 'get_subscription_price_string'"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin for managing subscription products on my website. When I add a subscription product to the cart, then go to the cart page, I see the following error when I expect to see the total:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'WC_CDP' does not have a method 'get_subscription_price_string' in /home/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 298

I can remove the warning in the settings defined in `wp_config.php`, but it does not resolve the the issue to display the total.

Has anyone come across this problem? How can I get the total to display correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title to include the error you are experiencing, so people can get a summary of the problem in the lists of questions. I also quoted your error in the body so it stands out. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more info on formatting.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation i found this error was caused by 'woocommerce custom display price' plugin